# Using Custom reduce function with Fake Groups

Tags: dc.js

I have line chart where I need to show frequency of order executions over the course of a day. These orders are grouped by time interval, for example every hour, using custom reduce functions. There could be an hour interval when there were no order executions, but I need to show that as a zero point on the line. I create a 'fake group' containing all the bins with a zero count...and the initial load of the page is correct.

However the line chart is one of 11 charts on the page, and needs to be updated when filters are applied to other charts. When I filter on another chart, the effects on this particular frequency line chart are incorrect. The dimension and the 'fake group' are used for the dc.chart.

I put console.log messages in the reduceRemove function and can see that there is something wrong...but not sure why.

Any thoughts on where I could be going wrong.

```
FrequencyVsTimeDimension = crossfilterData.dimension(function (d) { return d.execution_datetime; });

FrequencyVsTimeGroup = FrequencyVsTimeDimension.group(n_seconds_interval(interval));

FrequencyVsTimeGroup.reduce(
    function (p, d) { //reduceAdd
        if (d.execution_datetime in p.order_list) {
            p.order_list[d.execution_datetime] += 1;
        }
        else {
            p.order_list[d.execution_datetime] = 1;
            if (d.execution_type !== FILL) p.order_count++;
        }
        return p;
    },
    function (p, d) { //reduceRemove
        if (d.execution_type !== FILL) p.order_count--;

        p.order_list[d.execution_datetime]--;
        if (p.order_list[d.execution_datetime] === 0) {
            delete p.order_list[d.execution_datetime];
        }
        return p;
    },
    function () { //reduceInitial
        return { order_list: {}, order_count: 0 };
    }
);

var FrequencyVsTimeFakeGroup = ensure_group_bins(FrequencyVsTimeGroup, interval); // function that returns bins for all the intervals, even those without data.
```

Comment: Issue has been resolved.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! please use the dc.js tag for questions about the charting library - dc is quite something else.